# Keras : Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (299, 299, 3) but got array with shape (229, 229, 3)

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to train a inceptionv3 model in keras.

My dataset is preprocessed into a `229, 229, 3` shape.

```
print(data.shape)
print(type(data))
print(type(data[0]))
```

output

```
(1458, 229, 229, 3)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I initialize my model like this

```
import os, sys
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.applications import InceptionV3

model = InceptionV3()

# copile model
opt = SGD(lr=0.05)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Calling model.fit

```
# train the network
print("[INFO] training network...")
H = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(test_x, test_y),
              batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_of_epochs, verbose=1)
```

Then I get this error. I don't understand because the dimensions are correct.

```
[INFO] training network...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      2 print("[INFO] training network...")
      3 H = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(test_x, test_y),
----> 4               batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_of_epochs, verbose=1)
      5 
      6 model.save(model_save_path)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    749             feed_input_shapes,
    750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 751             exception_prefix='input')
    752 
    753         if y is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    136                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    137                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 138                             str(data_shape))
    139     return data
    140 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (299, 299, 3) but got array with shape (229, 229, 3)
```

**EDITS**

```
batch_size = 32
```

How images were resized

```
import imutils
import cv2

class AspectAwarePreprocessor:
    """
    CONTRUCTOR
    witdh : desired width
    height : desired height
    inter : interpolation method used when resizing the image
    """
    def __init__(self,width,height,inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.inter = inter

    """
    image : image to be preprocessed
    """
    def preprocess(self,image):
        # Get wdith and height of image
        (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
        dW = 0
        dH = 0

        # if width is the shorter dimension, resize image by width and crop height
        if w < h:
            image = imutils.resize(image, width=self.width,
                                   inter=self.inter)
            dH = int((image.shape[0] - self.height) / 2.0)

        # if height is the shorter dimension, resize image by height and crop width
        else:
            image = imutils.resize(image, height=self.height,
                               inter=self.inter)
            dW = int((image.shape[1] - self.width) / 2.0)

        # re-grab the width and height and use the deltas to crop the center of the image:
        (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
        image = image[dH:h - dH, dW:w - dW]

        # our image target image dimensions may be off by ± one pixel; therefore, we make a call to cv2.resize to 
        # ensure our output image has the desired width and height.
        return cv2.resize(image, (self.width, self.height),
                          interpolation=self.inter)
```

Comment: Can you show how have you defined your batch size? It seems the problem is related to that.

Comment: @AdamB. I updated it above. batch_size is 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding your network with an array of a wrong shape.
Your model is expecting an array of shape `(299, 299, 3)` but you give to it an array of shape `(229, 229, 3)`

(2**9**9, 2**9**9, 3) IS NOT (2**2**9, 2**2**9, 3)

So either you need to reshape your data with a shape of `(299, 299, 3)`, or you need to change the expected shape of InceptionV3:

```
model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, input_shape=(229, 229, 3))
```

You have to use `include_top=False` if you want to specify the input shape **other than the default one**.

https://keras.io/applications/#inceptionv3

Hope i helped you !

Comment: Hi, can you explain how the dimensions are wrong. Since they look exactly the same. Also include_top=False, I'm just learning keras and in this particular example not trying to use transfer learning. Just train inceptionv3 from fresh on my dataset and classify.

Comment: @ Enzio `299` is not the same as `229`. I mean they are kinda similar, but still not the same ...

Comment: This answer is __wrong__. `include_top` is to change the number of output classes, not the image shape.

Comment: As said by sxeros, look closely, it's not the same numbers. Include_top = False mean you will not have the last classifier, so you need to create your own. If you just want to train on your data, the easiest way is to reshape your data to (299, 299, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Pre-trained models can only accept specific shapes. You need to resize your pictures. I suggest you use `PIL`.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

X_train = Image.fromarray(X_train).resize((299, 299))
X_train = np.array(X_train)
```

That's an example of how to proceed.

Comment: I updated the code showing the part where I resize the images. My images are resized to `(299, 299, 3)` as shown above. I don't understand.

Comment: If your images are really `(299, 299, 3)` then there is no reason why you'd get this error message.

Comment: If that's the shape, you are not resizing them properly. Before the `return` statement of your `preprocess` function, write `assert np.array(image).shape == (299, 299, 3), 'Error, the picture shape is {}'.format(np.array(image).shape)` and make sure that passes the assertion test